# How i can remove particular row from table using jquery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

**First Problem:**

When user deleted particular row then i have to remove that row only with out page refresh.
Deleting row using ajax. How can i do this

**Second Problem:**
Actually i am calculating the when ever page hits from that day to previous 7 days.
But i want when page hits today i have to retrieve previous week 
Means from sunday(20 Nov 2011) to saturday (20 Nov 2011)
When page hits on next monday so i have to retrieve this week records
Means from sunday(27 Nov 2011) to saturday (03 Dec 2011)

```
function authenticate(){
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "authentication.php",                 
data: $("#login_form").serialize(),
success: function(msg){
    if(msg==1){
    $('#delete').html("success"); //if success message appear only i have to remove particular row
    }) 
    }else{
    $('#delete').html("error");
    }
},
error:function(msg){
    alert(msg);
    $('#delete').dialog("close"); 
}              
});
}
<div style='display: none;' id='delete'></div>
<table border="1">
<tr>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Public Id</th>
    <th>Pass</th>
    <th></th>
</tr>
<?php
$select = $db->select ()
    ->from ( 'test', '*' )
    ->where ( 'user_id = ?', 1 )
    ->where ( 'test.created > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)' );
$tourDetails = $db->fetchAll ( $select );
$i = 0;
foreach ( $tourDetails as $row1 ) {
    $i ++;
    $title = $row1 ['title'];
    $PublicId = $row1 ['public_id'];
    if (($i % 2) == 0 ) {
        $rowResponse =  prepareRow ( true, $title, $PublicId);
        echo $rowResponse;
    } else {
        $rowResponse = prepareRow ( false, $title, $PublicId);
        echo $rowResponse;
    }
}
function prepareRow($flag, $title, $PublicId) {
$rowResponse = "";
if ($flag) {
    $rowResponse .= '<tr class="even">';
} else {
    $rowResponse .= '<tr class="odd" >';
}
    $rowResponse .= '   
    <td> ' . $title . ' </td>
    <td> ' . $publicId . ' </td>
    <td><p><a onclick=openDialog("'. $PublicId .'","delete") href="#" id="dialog_link"> 
    Delete </a></p>
    </td>';
return $rowResponse;
?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use jQuery's [nth-child](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) selector.

```
$("table#mytableid tr:nth-child(2)").remove();
```

This will remove the second row, for example. Make sure your table has an ID or a class so that you select it more easily (not accidentally removing 2nd row of EVERY table on the page, in case you have more)...

EDIT

From what I see in your code, you could select the parent tr element from your onclick event and then either send it to the function as a new parameter (which you would remove it the ajax returns success) or remove it right away... or whatever you want.

Comment: i have to remove not 2nd row user deleted row

Comment: I just gave you an example... you can either find the row number of the deleted row and put that instead of 2 or assing an ID to the row upon deleting and then use the vikky's approach.

Comment: you can use the index of that specific clicked element.

Comment: Thanks for helping completed it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#myTableRow').remove(); 

 This works fine if your row has an id, such as:
<tr id="myTableRow"><td>blah</td></tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

use `msg.d`

for example:

```
if(msg.d == 1)
```

Comment: Code only answers are normally discouraged.  Care to elaborate a bit.  How does this compare to the other answers?